# How can I model interactions between two groups of features using kernel methods?

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick

Basically I am looking to fit a linear regression model using two groups of features that are completely different in nature (genomic data and say... weather data). I'm looking to extract main effects from each group plus an interaction effect between groups.

So far I have been using [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3931944/) as a reference.

As I understand this is achievable using a kernel function separately on each group of features (In my case, a "genomic kernel" and an "environmental kernel"). For the interaction, the paper I linked uses a direct product between the genomic and environmental kernels, but I am wondering if there are more general methods to model the interaction between groups of features (as in, I want to test different kernels for this)

I am going through the literature on Gaussian Processes without luck. Maybe I am failing at searching the right terms, as I am not from a maths/stats background

Quoting from [Chapter 4](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf) on Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning:

---

*"Consider a function $f(x)$, where $x$ is D-dimensional. An additive model has the form $f(x) = c + \sum\limits_{i=1}^D f_i(x_i)$, i.e. a linear combination of functions of one variable. If the individual $f_i$’s are taken to be independent stochastic processes, then the covariance function of $f$ will have the form of a direct sum. If we now admit interactions of two variables, so that $f(x) = c + \sum\limits_{i=1}^D f_i(x_i)+ \sum\limits_{ij,j<i} f_{ij}(x_i,x_j)$ and the various $f_i$’s and $f_{ij}$’s are independent stochastic processes, then the covariance function will have the form $k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^D k_i(x_i, x_i')+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^D\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} k_{ij}(x_i,x_j;x_i',x_j')$. Indeed this process can be extended further to provide a functional ANOVA decomposition, ranging from a simple additive model up to full interaction of all D input variables."*

---

This shows me that is possible to explicitly assign different kernels for interactions between features. However, I have hundreds of thousands of genomic features (SNP data) and hundreds of environmental features (temperature, rainfall, etc.), modelling interactions one by one like that is just not feasible.

I wonder if there are general Gaussian Process methods for modelling interactions between groups of features. Or at least tips on how do I search for this.